# Junit : unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, maven-3

i have a problem. My pom can not start the test. I get this exception:

```
Could not transfer artifact org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:pom:5.9.0 from/to examplerepo-releases (https://xxx/artifactory/examplerepo-releases/): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

My POM.xml can you see here:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>7</source>
                    <target>7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
...
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-params -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-migrationsupport -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-migrationsupport</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I searched other entrys on this forum but they were no help
I tried with various pom configurations, but none were successful

Comment: You have wrong configured jdk or just missing the needed certificate in your JDK (cacerts file). apart from that I would strongly recommend to use BOM files for JUnit Jupiter instead defining each component separetely...

Comment: Ah missed one thing. You have configured source/target with 7 which will not work because JUnit Jupiter requires at mimimum JDK8 which means at least for the test you have to use JDK8